# LinkedList implementation for removal method python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class LinkedList:
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None

def print_all(self):
    current = self.head
    while current != None:
        print(current.get_data())
        current = current.get_next()

def add(self, item): 
    new = Node(item)
    new.set_next(self.head)
    self.head = new

def remove_from_tail(self):
    #Method to be implemented needs to remove the end item of the linked list by tracking the current viewed item and tracking the previous item and setting the 'next' node field to None.
```

An example of a function call

```
my_list = LinkedList()

my_list.add('cat')
my_list.add('bit')
my_list.add('ask')

result = my_list.remove_from_tail()

print('Removed:', result)
my_list.print_all()
```

Expected output:

```
Removed: cat
ask
bit
```

Assume Node class is implemented by standard conventions (get_next, set_next, get_data, set_data, etc)

I've been trying to do this for hours but I know its a relatively simple exercise I just don't know how to define the `remove_from_tail` function.

Answer (score 0):

Pinch the basic implementation from `print_all()`:

```
class LinkedList:
    #[..]

    def print_all(self):
        current = self.head
        while current != None:
            print(current.get_data())
            current = current.get_next()

    #[..]

    def remove_from_tail(self):
        current = self.head

        # Check for an empty list
        if current = None:
            return None

        # Check for an one-item list
        if current.get_next() == None:
            data = current.get_data()
            self.head = None
            return data

        # Multi item list
        while current.get_next():
            previous = current
            current = current.get_next()

        data = current.get_data()
        previous.set_next(None)
        return data
```

[Edit: Oops]

Comment: I did this! but it keeps showing the wrong output and basically its wrong. Ill provide a screenshot to make it more clear and understandable whats going on: 
\
output: http://imgur.com/dvg5Qxg
what I wrote: http://imgur.com/F3XLgNx

Comment: Oh, er, whoops. >_<    That took all too much staring to see; you do `data = previous.get_data()` and return it, and it says "cat". Previous shouldn't be "cat", it should be the item-before-the-last-one, it should be "ask". We both wrote code which goes too far - it walks off the end of the list and then stops, when "current" is off the end of the list, and "previous" is the last item in the list. Then we just set the last item to point to None - which it already was, so that does nothing. I've edited my code so it "looks ahead" and stops just *before* current goes off the end of the list.

Comment: I also remember coming across what you edited but things got weird: 1)http://imgur.com/LEnbJjb / 2) http://imgur.com/G2VkhtQ
This was done with the newly edited code you wrote

Comment: Ugh. In that case, I retract my answer

Comment: Yeah Im so damn clueless for this, heads been spinning for 2 days

Comment: Crash looks like it's because I wasn't thinking about empty lists and one-item lists. Returning the wrong item is because now 'current' is the last item, not 'previous'. Should be 'current.get_data' instead. Answer updated again (I'll just call this iterative development without test cases...).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks for all your help seriously! going to study this thoroughly and compare why each of my previous cases never worked